# Core data dirty flag not being set

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsdocument

I have a core data document based cocoa app that is working well except for one slightly odd problem.

For some reason, if I make a change to any of my fields the menu/window don't seem to recognize it - ie. the red close button doesn't get the black 'dirty' indicator and the File/Save menu item isn't enabled.  However, if I attempt to close the application (via command-Q), I do get the popup asking me if I want to save my changes.

It seems that the document's dirty flag is being set, but the window/menu items aren't reacting to it.  I am curious as to where I might look to see why this might be the case.  I suspect that it may have something to do with my window not knowing about my ManagedObjectContext...

The only slightly atypical behaviour is that my document's makeWindowControllers method has been overridden and I am adding my window controllers using a call to my document's [self addWindowController:xxx] method.  My window controllers subclass from NSWindowController so I had to add my own instance variable to each window controller to hold the ManagedObjectContext, but I suspect that this isn't getting passed to the window/menu.  Not sure what the normal pattern is here...

Anyway, any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks in part to TechZen, and also re-reading my own question (in particular, where I said "*I suspect that it may have something to do with my window not knowing about my ManagedObjectContext*") I started to look at the bindings for my WindowController subclass.

As it turned out, I hadn't bound the *window* outlet for the *File's Owner* to my actual NSWindow.  As soon as I did that, the black dirty dot and the window's menus started behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From the description it sounds like your UI elements are not actually bound to the document itself. If so, then the UI elements are not observing the document and are not reacting to changes in the document. Check the bindings.

Comment: The UI fields are definitely bound to the managed objects.  For example, if I make a bunch of changes to objects via my UI fields, press command-Q, enter a filename and Save, then re-open that file my changes have persisted.

Comment: Are the `Save` menu and the button bound properly? It's been a while since I worked with a document based app but you do need to bind the menus to the data model so they can reflect if a change has been made. They just won't automatically know that the document has been updated. That is usually done to the window controller IIRC.